# PHP: How to replace a segment of a string with some random text from a list

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string with a URL in it and I wish to find and replace a predictable part of the URL with something else.

Basically, how to randomise a choice of subdomain.

For example, `$file` contains: `https://url.foo.com/w_Path/File.doc` how do I check if `$file` contains `url.foo.com`, and if so, replace the `url.foo.com` portion with either `differentsubdomain.foo.com` or `anotherplace.foo.com` or `someotherplace.foo.com`?

#### Input:

```
$file = "https://url.foo.com/w_Path/SomeFile.ext";
$params['file'] = $file
```

#### Desired output:

```
$file = "https://url.foo.com/w_Path/SomeFile.ext";
 // list of subdomains = "differentsubdomain", "anotherplace", "someotherplace";
 // find 'url.foo.com' part of $file and replace with random subdomain choice from list
 // $file = "https://someotherplace.foo.com/w_Path/SomeFile.ext";
$params['file'] = $file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values you randomly want to select into an array, use `array_rand()` to pick a random element (this returns the key, so you have to select the value from the array again based on the key you got), then use `str_replace()` to replace the value.

If the search-string ("needle", in your case `url.foo.com`)  is not found, no replacement will happen. Beware, that this will replace all instances of that needle if it occurs more than once.

```php
$random_values = ['differentsubdomain.foo.com', 'anotherplace.foo.com', 'someotherplace.foo.com'];
$random = $random_values[array_rand($random_values)];


$file = "https://url.foo.com/w_Path/SomeFile.ext";
$file = str_replace('url.foo.com', $random, $file);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/um719

You can also use `array_flip()`, and use `array_rand()` on that to achieve the same result.

```
$random = array_rand(array_flip($random_values));
```

- Live demo of that at https://3v4l.org/X5KA3

Comment: Yes, just put that code in a loop that loops over all the relevant files (which is represented by elements in the array)

Comment: Can't really be more specific without seeing the structure of the array.

Comment: Just loop over it, pass by reference (the `&` in the `foreach`) and edit. https://3v4l.org/TcP5S