# PHP: How to find and replace values for a key with random text from a list in a varying-length array

Tags: php, arrays, string, list, replace

I have a varying array for a playlist, containing media/source URLs for each item. Like this:

```php
$playlist = array(
  array(
    "title" => "something",
    "sources" => array(
      array(
        "file" => "https://url.somedomain.com/path/file1.mp3"
      )
    ), 
    "description" => "somedesc",
    "image" => "http://imagepath/",
    "file" => "https://url.somedomain.com/path/file1.mp3"
  ),
  array(
    "title" => "elsewaa", 
    "sources" => array(
      array(
        "file" => "https://url.somedomain.com/someother/file2.mp3"
      )
    ), 
    "description" => "anotherdesc", 
    "image" => "http://someotherimagepath/", 
    "file" => "https://url.somedomain.com/someother/file2.mp3"
  )
);
```

How do I find and replace the values in the `file` keys to 'randomise' the choice of subdomain?

For example, if the `file` key contains `url.foo.com`, how do I replace the `url.foo.com` portion of the array value with either `differentsubdomain.foo.com` or `anotherplace.foo.com` or `someotherplace.foo.com`?

I was kindly offered a solution for a single string in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235713/php-how-to-replace-a-segment-of-a-string-with-some-random-text-from-a-list) that used `str_replace` (thanks Qirel!), but I need a solution that tackles the above array configuration specifically.

All the nesting in the array does my head in!

Is it possible to adapt Qirel's suggestion somehow?

```
$random_values = ['differentsubdomain.foo.com', 'anotherplace.foo.com', 'someotherplace.foo.com'];
$random = $random_values[array_rand($random_values)];
// str_replace('url.foo.com', $random, $file);
```

Comment: So, just to be correct, you want to replace the subdomain in `file` key with a random one from a list? (ignoring the `sources` array)

Comment: I need to change the values nested in `sources` and also the `file` key on its own at the end. Basically check and replace any/all references in `file` that match `url.foo.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just asking how to access members in nested arrays, I think you want this:

```php
$random_values = ['differentsubdomain.foo.com', 'anotherplace.foo.com', 'someotherplace.foo.com'];

// Iterate through the array, altering the items by reference.
foreach ($playlist as &$item) {
   $random_key = array_rand($random_values);
   $new_domain = $random_values[$random_key];
   $item['file'] = str_replace('url.foo.com', $new_domain);
   $item['sources'][0]['file'] = str_replace('url.foo.com', $new_domain);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using recursion to replace the subdomains in any keys named `file` with a random one.

```php
function replaceUrlHost(&$array, $hostDomain, $subdomains)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = replaceUrlHost($value, $hostDomain, $subdomains);
            continue;
        }

        if ($key !== 'file') {
            continue;
        }

        $hostname = parse_url($value, PHP_URL_HOST);

        if (strpos($hostname, $hostDomain) === false) {
            continue;
        }

        $array[$key] = str_replace(
            $hostname,
            $subdomains[array_rand($subdomains)] . '.' . $hostDomain,
            $value
        );
    }

    return $array;
}

// usage
$subdomains = ['bar', 'baz', 'bing', 'bop'];
$out = replaceUrlHost($playlist, 'somedomain.com', $subdomains);
```